# Magento rewards cart does not return the total points to be spent

Tags: session-cookies, magento-1.9, checkout, shopping-cart, points

I have integrated the Magento rewards program to be the main currency insted of money. Users have to earn points and spend them as the methhod of payment for all products.

Currently I am experiencing an issue where the User tries to add items to the cart, it allows to add items over the value which could be spent.

ex : 
Current points = 20000
Cart value = 22000

But when I go to back end and save the product again it works fine and trows the message "Not enough points to check out".

Tried all the various things clearing cache, re-indexing, updating product programatically etc. nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using the controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add event to add a observer which would  check if the points available is greater than the points required to buy the product, if it is not you could prevent the product from being added to the cart and show an error message to the user.

If it is possible to add your code to the question I would be able to provide a better solution to your problem.